# Reduce the Scale of Date on X-axis in r using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have Dateframe 4 columns with 1600 rows and Date as one of the column. while ploting the grouped data in a single chart the X-axis has too many points. I need to reduce the scale with month-year format.

```
library(scales)

library(ggplot2)

    ggplot(site_sales_day, aes(x=Date, y=log(Sales), color=grouping,group=1,cex=0.2))+geom_line(size=2)+scale_x_date(format = "%m-%Y",breaks = '1 month')
```

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtUif.jpg)
[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV21c.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you need is fewer breaks on the x-axis, simply augment the space between breaks by specifying longer time units to the scale_x_date command with the date_break parameter. For instance, draw breaks in quarters with  scale_x_date(date_format = "%m-%Y", date_breaks = '3 months')

```
ggplot(site_sales_day, aes(x=Date, y=log(Sales), color=grouping,group=1,cex=0.2)) +
    geom_line(size=2) +
    scale_x_date(date_format = "%m-%Y", date_breaks = '3 months')
```

Comment: Velasquez tried increasing the breaks but getting the following error

_Error in scale_x_date(format = "%m-%Y", breaks = "3 months") : 
  unused argument (format = "%m-%Y")_

Comment: Thanks @velasquez for your prompt responses just added breaks = date_breaks('3 months') to you code and it got executed.

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(labels = date_format("%m-%Y"), ...)`?